# PHP - how to remove all tags (HTML JS PHP CSS JQUERY) from a web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to have just the content of a web page. Let's say I want take the content from this url for [example](http://www.booking.com/reviews/es/hotel/royal.html?aid=304142;sid=56e38d55a38ec2df6fe4622827e89675;dcid=1), but on this page there are HTML JS and other tags and I want to remove them all. 
What I have so far is this

```
$raw_text = file_get_contents( 'http://www.booking.com/reviews/es/hotel/royal.html?aid=304142;sid=56e38d55a38ec2df6fe4622827e89675;dcid=1' );
$rm_html = strip_tags($raw_text);
```

How can I remove all kind of tags and just have the text that there is in the current page?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "content" of a page?

Comment: strip_tags didn't work?

Comment: @arkascha I want just the text there is in there so I can process it later

Comment: @Jeremy Thille removes only the HTML tags.it still gets js in there

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but can you use a regex to get all content within the tags?

Comment: @WesleySkeen Certainly such thing is possible in any language, but it is a _huge_ effort to implement something that works reliably. Especially for pages that do not strictly obey markup syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be not to implement something yourself by means of php, but to use something which is already finished, for example the `lynx` text browser:

```
lynx --dump http://some.example.org/page.html
```

This dumps all text found on a page onto standard out where you can apply further processing filters. Certainly you can also use shell means to pipe the output into files or whatever. You can also call this from within php if you prefer, as long as the utility is installed (or something similar, like `links`).

Comment: what if the computer tha i will run it don't have it?

Comment: Well, then you have to either install it or use an alternative, as suggested. If that is not possible, then obviously you cannot use this approach.